# Captioning different elements

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, captions

I need 2 different Figure captions: Examples and Figures. If I use the `\renewcommand`, every time a figures appears, the counter won't stop and keep adding, like: Example 1. Figure 2. Example 3. Figure 4...

And I need: Example 1. Figure 1. Example 2. Figure 2.

Also, is it possible to make these 2 lists separate at the `ToC`?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Like playing the Lotto (Lottery, sorry, couldn't resist ;-)) the result is by chance and we can only guess what you're really trying to do.  Please post your code here. And you're asking to different questions, actually

Comment: I would say you want to create a `\newcounter{Example}` and an associated `\newenvironment{Example}`, which internally calls `\addtocounter{Example}{1}`.

Comment: If you don't know what is a minimal working example (MWE), see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf: `\refstepcounter{Example}` is to be preferred **if** cross-referencing is required, however

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I did not know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `float` might do what you need.

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled} % Defines how the new floats should look like.
\newfloat{example}{htbp}{loe} % Defines a new float environment, with captions written to a file with extension `loe` (list of examples).
\floatname{example}{Example} % Label for captions
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{example}
  \centering
  This is an example.
  \caption{Some example}\label{ex:a}
\end{example}
...
See example~\ref{ex:a}.
...
\listof{example}{List of Examples} % Print a list of captions of all examples.
```

To let the list of figures (and tables) appear in the table of contents, you can add

```
% Add list of figures and tables to table of contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

to the preamble. To add also the lists of new floats (like the list of examples) to the table of contents, it seems we have to patch the `\listof` command provided by the `float` package. Add the following lines immediately after `\usepackage{float}`.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
% Add the lists of new floats to table of contents
\makeatletter
%\xpatchcmd\listof{\@starttoc}{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}\@starttoc}{}{}% For article class
\xpatchcmd\listof{\@starttoc}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}\@starttoc}{}{}% For report and book class
\makeatother
```

Here is a complete example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 % Add list of figures and tables to table of contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% Add the lists of new floats to table of contents
\makeatletter
%\xpatchcmd\listof{\@starttoc}{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}\@starttoc}{}{}% For article class
\xpatchcmd\listof{\@starttoc}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}\@starttoc}{}{}% For report and book class
\makeatother
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{example}{htbp}{loe}
\floatname{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listof{example}{List of Examples}
\chapter{The first chapter}
This document shows two figures, \ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b},
as well two examples, \ref{ex:a} and \ref{ex:b}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Some figure}\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\begin{example}
  \centering
  This is an example for something.
  \caption{Some example}\label{ex:a}
\end{example}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Another figure}\label{fig:b}
\end{figure}
\begin{example}
  \centering
  Yet another example.
  \caption{Another example}\label{ex:b}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you very much!

I didn't use the \floatstyle{ruled}
Hopefully this won't bring any problem to the document.

Comment: @Lotto Which `\floatstyle` to use is a matter of taste/design. I just used it for demonstration purposes. The options are `plain` (the default if you omit `\floatstyle`), `plaintop`, `boxed`, and `ruled`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using package `tocbasic`, which is used by all KOMA-classes.
With a KOMA-class, package `float` isn't the best choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[
    type=example,
    types=examples,
    float,
name=Example]{loe}
\setuptoc{loe}{totoc}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\rule{.8\textwidth}{.4pt}

This document shows two figures, \ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b},
as well two examples, \ref{ex:a} and \ref{ex:b}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Some figure}\label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\begin{example}
    \centering
    This is an example for something.
    \caption{Some example}\label{ex:a}
\end{example}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Another figure}\label{fig:b}
\end{figure}
\begin{example}
    \centering
    Yet another example.
    \caption{Another example}\label{ex:b}
\end{example}
\listoffigures
\listofexamples
\end{document}
```